# 1 Tim 2:12: What about a woman prophesying with authority over a man?

Tags: prophecy, gender

For as long as I can remember I have implicitly read this verse as specifically referring to office-authority, IE church leadership role. Given Paul's implicit endorsement of women prophesying in 1 Cor 11:5; I am considering which takes precedence in a moment where a woman is prophesying when it involves being a position of authority over a man.

Being a little charismatic is tough. I ask as a matter of personal interest.

aside: I'm currently evaluating whether this may be a non-issue. When a person is fully humbled under God's authority, everything seems to sort itself out.

Comment: See [*1 Corinthians 11:1-16 - Its Issues and Implications*](https://bible.org/seriespage/22-1-corinthians-111-16-its-issues-and-implications).

Comment: It might be helpful to quote the 1 Tim passage in full if that is where this question starts, but what would be most helpful for clarity's sake would be to re-phrase to make the question clearer - I'm not currently sure exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @JackDouglas can you please be more specific about what is unclear? The question is in the subject, and again in the last clause of first paragraph. Please read more carefully. Dick Harfield had no trouble discerning this and providing insight.

Comment: @ben+ **(A.)** The objection I have to your question is that you do not distinguish between the "gift of prophecy" and the "role of prophet"--even King Saul prophesied, but that didn't make him a "Prophet".  **(B.)** Are Women who are in the Role of Prophetess, exempt from these restrictions? The same tests for self-proclaimed prophets would apply.  **(C.)** Acts 21:9 could serve as a New Testament basis for women as Prophets--but there are translation issues. **(D.)** As for the "gift of prophecy" , this was to be done in "order", and accountability was from the Church, not one man or woman.

Comment: @e.s.kohen thank you for the useful criticism. I will think about this more

Answer (score -2, accepted):

During the course of the first century, Christianity seems to have undergone a cultural change in its attitude to women in church. In his undisputed epistles, Paul treats women as the equal to men in the church.

In Romans 16:1, Paul identified Phoebe as a deacon of the church at Cenchrea, the port city of Corinth. In this role she must have had some authority over lay Christians:

> [Romans 16:1](http://biblehub.com/niv/romans/16.htm) (NIV): I commend to you our sister Phoebe, a deacon of the church in Cenchreae.

Then, in Romans 16:3 and 1 Corinthians 16:19, Paul mentions Priscilla as the equal of her husband, Aquila, as co-workers with him and as co-hosts of the church which met in their house. There is no hint here that Paul thought of Priscilla as secondary to Aquila, or that she should be subservient.

> [Romans 16:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%2016%3A3-5): Greet Priscilla and Aquila, my co-workers in Christ Jesus.
>
> [1 Corinthians 16:19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2016:19): The churches of Asia salute you. Aquila and Priscilla salute you much in the Lord, with the church that is in their house.

In 1 Corinthians 11:5, Paul speaks of women prophesying in church, only requiring that they cover their heads when doing so. [It is unclear](http://www.bible-researcher.com/headcoverings3.html) why Paul so stridently insisted that women cover their heads, but in this there is no suggestion that women must remain silent.

> 1 Corinthians 11:5: But every woman that prayeth or prophesieth with her head uncovered dishonoureth her head: for that is even all one as if she were shaven.

---

In complete contrast to verse 11:5, we then find 1 Corinthians 14:34-35, which demands silence of women in church. Silence would literally have prevented Phoebe from performing her role of deacon at Cenchrea.

> 1 Corinthians 14:34-35: Let your women keep silence in the churches: for it is not permitted unto them to speak; but they are commanded to be under obedience as also saith the law. And if they will learn any thing, let them ask their husbands at home: for it is a shame for women to speak in the church.

Bart D. Ehrman, author of *[Forged](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0062012622)* believes that 1 Corinthians 14:34-35 is a later interpolation, saying (page 245) if they were allowed to speak in chapter 11, how could they be told not to speak in chapter 14. Although no manuscript omits this passage, Gordon D. Fee, author of *[The First Epistle to the Corinthians (The New International Commentary on the New Testament)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0802825079)* also believes it could be an interpolation, on the grounds that some manuscripts place the passage slightly later in the text. At the very least, this passage is at odds with Paul's consistent acceptance of an active role for women in church.

This brings us to First Timothy, which clearly requires women to have no authority over a man:

> [1 Timothy 2:12](http://www.biblestudytools.com/1-timothy/2-12.html):  I do not permit a woman to teach or to have authority over a man; she must be silent.

Ehrman cites (*Forged*, page 98) the British scholar A. N. Harrison, who wrote an important study of the pastoral letters (*1 Timothy, 2 Timothy, Titus*) in 1921. Harrison found that more than one third of the words used in these epistles do not occur in any of the other Pauline letters of the New Testament, with most of these words coming into use by Christian authors living in the second century. Ehrman says that suggests that the author is using a vocabulary that was becoming more common after the days of Paul, and that he lived after Paul. In fact, the scholarly consensus is that *1 Timothy* was written in the second century.

The conclusion to be drawn from the above analysis is that 1 Corinthians 11:5 should have precedence over 1 Timothy 2:12, because the views expressed in 1 Corinthians 11:5 are Paul's. He supported Phoebe as a deacon, treated Priscilla as an equal to Aquila and did not criticise women for prophesying in church. The views expressed in 1 Timothy do not carry the same authority.

Comment: @D. Harfield, RE: E1 Corinthians 14:34-35 is a later interpolation. Gordon Fee also considerd it a secondary reading. Only problem is we don't have any other readings. Its in every manuscript we have.

Comment: @Dick: **(A.)** Paul did not command women to be silent in the "Church Community", but rather the Assemblies--during the "services," which wouldn't stop Deacons/Servants fulfilling their responsibilities; **(B.)** "Deacon" is a horrible a translation, actually a transliteration, and denotes "servant". **(C.)** Today, WE dispute if there was a distinction between authority of men and women, but Paul was not at all ambiguous; **(D.)** Analysis of Aquila, Priscila, Phoebe, etc, are not analogous--IF the Original Poster was talking about Women as "Prophets", and not just the "Gift of Prophecy".

Comment: @C.StirlingBartholomew Thank you for your information, which I have incorporated in my answer. You will have noted that I originally left open whether or not this is an interpolation, and I still do so.  I agree that we need more evidence before asserting this to be the most likely explanation.

Comment: @D.Harfield, On the displacement of 1Cor 14:34-35 in the western text see  **Corinthian Women Prophets**  A. C. Wire 1990, pp. 149-52, A. Thiselton 1Cor NIGTC p. 1148.  A. C. Wire demonstrates the displacement in the western text  (D F G 88  a b d f g)  all stem from the ancestor of D & G which Wire considers a single greek manuscript. Wire accepts Alexandrian reading, the earliest wittiness being p46.